# rsync - exclude all except some folders

Tags: linux, debian, rsync

I need to run sync over whole system and include only few dirs and files, but this command does not synchronize anything.

```
rsync -avxn --include='etc/php/' --include='usr/local/' --exclude='*' / server:/
```

I try it on Debian 10 and rsync 3.1.3

Comment: I guess you'll need the `-r` parameter so that rsync will [recursive sync the folders](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: Parameter `-r` is included in `-a`. Parameter `-a` equals `-rlptgoD`.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26790074/5625547), try: `--include='/etc/php/**' --include='/usr/local/**' --exclude='*'`

Comment: `--include='/etc/php/**'` I tried this and it not working too...